# Convert a list to plain string exactly like a string pattern

Tags: c#

Please check the code bellow. I am trying to convert a list of item to plain string with a specific string pattern which you will find in code comments. One thing is during convert i also need to remove any white space and any character before `:` for ASIN property. As you can see i already tried `.ToString()` but this cant convert list values. Any idea how can i do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //asign some demo data
            var tpd = new List<ThirdPartyData>();

            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "mark: NsQf8", type = 0, Price = 7, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });
            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "fD5tsQ ", type = 1, Price = 13, IsPrime = 0, OutOfStock = 0 });
            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "notmark: tvQtsu", type = 1, Price = 14, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });

            //this tpd list should be converted string like bellow-

            //Converted String output should be like this- 'ASIN-NsQf8,type-0,Price-7,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1:ASIN-fD5tsQ,type-1,Price-13,IsPrime-0,OutOfStock-0:ASIN-tvQtsu,type-1,Price-14,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1'

            string output = tpd.ToString();//i tried it not works

        }

    }

    class ThirdPartyData
    {
        public string ASIN { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int IsPrime { get; set; }
        public int OutOfStock { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to `foreach` through the list adding text to a StringBuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I understand but I wanted to know how can i get output exactly like my example output string? Can u answer that please?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why did you think that just `ToString()` would work and "magically" (1) strip your ASIN prefixes and (2) "guess" your `-` and `:` delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to write a method that takes in a `ThirdPartyData` object and returns the string of property names and values formatted as you have specified (this code could also be put in an override of the `ToString()` method in the `ThirdPartyData` class if you have control of the class and believe this is the best string representation of the class):

```
private static string TpdToString(ThirdPartyData input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    var asinParts = input.ASIN?.Split(':') ?? new[] {"[NULL]"};
    var asin = asinParts.Length > 1 ? asinParts[1].Trim() : asinParts[0].Trim();

    return $"ASIN-{asin},type-{input.type},Price-{input.Price}," + 
        $"IsPrime-{input.IsPrime},OutOfStock-{input.OutOfStock}";
}
```

Then you can simply set your output to the result of joining each item's string with a `':'` character:

```
string output = string.Join(":", tpd.Select(TpdToString));
```

**Sample**

```
private static void Main()
{
    //asign some demo data
    var tpd = new List<ThirdPartyData>
    {
        new ThirdPartyData {ASIN = "mark: NsQf8", type = 0, Price = 7, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1},
        new ThirdPartyData {ASIN = "fD5tsQ ", type = 1, Price = 13, IsPrime = 0, OutOfStock = 0},
        new ThirdPartyData {ASIN = "notmark: tvQtsu", type = 1, Price = 14, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1}
    };

    var output = string.Join(":", tpd.Select(TpdToString));

    Console.WriteLine(output);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, you define a method to convert your custom class to your desired string representation:

```
class ThirdPartyData
{
    public string ASIN { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int IsPrime { get; set; }
    public int OutOfStock { get; set; }

    public string ToExport()
    {
        return $"ASIN-{ASIN},type-{type},...";
    }
}
```

Then you map your class instances to their string representation:

```
string[] tpdStrings = tpd.Select(t => t.ToExport()).ToArray();
```

And then you join those strings using your desired delimiter:

```
string output = String.Join(":", tpdStrings);
```

Comment: This requires little change in `ToExport` since it does not cut off part of ASIN that is before the `:` symbol.

Comment: @Caldazar: Good point. Since my intent is to teach the OP (and provide a reference for future readers) rather than to provide a copy&paste solution, I will leave that as an exercise and give the hint that string's `Split` and `Trim` methods are helpful here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the code below shows: Override Tostring, and Also use string.join to create your string in the main method. I also recommend using a Regex to wipe out all the empty spaces as you can see below:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //asign some demo data
            var tpd = new List<ThirdPartyData>();

            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "mark: NsQf8", type = 0, Price = 7, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });
            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "fD5tsQ ", type = 1, Price = 13, IsPrime = 0, OutOfStock = 0 });
            tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "notmark: tvQtsu", type = 1, Price = 14, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });

            //this tpd list should be converted string like bellow-

            //Converted String output should be like this- 'ASIN-NsQf8,type-0,Price-7,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1:ASIN-fD5tsQ,type-1,Price-13,IsPrime-0,OutOfStock-0:ASIN-tvQtsu,type-1,Price-14,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1'


            var strings = new List<string>();
            tpd.ForEach(item => strings.Add(item.ToString()));
            string output =string.Join(",", strings);
        }

    }

    class ThirdPartyData
    {
        readonly Regex WhiteSpaceRegex = new Regex("[ ]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        public string ASIN { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int IsPrime { get; set; }
        public int OutOfStock { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string[] asin = ASIN.Split(':');
            string asinString = string.Empty;
            if (asin.Length >= 1)
            {
                asinString = WhiteSpaceRegex.IsMatch(asin[1]) ? WhiteSpaceRegex.Replace(asin[1], string.Empty).Trim() : asin[1]; ;
            }
            return $"ASIN-{asinString},type-{type},Price-{Price},IsPrime-{IsPrime},OutOfStock-{OutOfStock}";
        }
```

Comment: is that also removes all white character of ASIN? I need to remove all char with `:` also remove all white space if available

Comment: Look at the code now...I added a regex, that removes all the white spaces. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, but I think that you must realize ToString() in your class.

```
string output = string.Join(
      ",",
      Array.ConvertAll<ThirdPartyData, string>(tpd, Convert.ToString)
    );
```

Comment: FYI, if you override `ToString()` in the `ThirdPartyData` class, then the above could be simplified to `string output = string.Join(",", tpd);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. The missing part was a projection of the ThirdPartyData objects to a String. After that you only need to make a join of those strings. That's all.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        //asign some demo data
        var tpd = new List<ThirdPartyData>();

        tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "mark: NsQf8", type = 0, Price = 7, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });
        tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "fD5tsQ ", type = 1, Price = 13, IsPrime = 0, OutOfStock = 0 });
        tpd.Add(new ThirdPartyData { ASIN = "notmark: tvQtsu", type = 1, Price = 14, IsPrime = 1, OutOfStock = 1 });

        //this tpd list should be converted string like bellow-

        //Converted String output should be like this- 'ASIN-NsQf8,type-0,Price-7,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1:ASIN-fD5tsQ,type-1,Price-13,IsPrime-0,OutOfStock-0:ASIN-tvQtsu,type-1,Price-14,IsPrime-1,OutOfStock-1'

        var individual = tpd.Select(t => $"ASIN-{ (t.ASIN.Split(new char[]{ ':' }).Length == 1 ? t.ASIN.Split(new char[] { ':' })[0].Trim() : t.ASIN.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].Trim()) },type-{t.type},Price-{t.Price},IsPrime-{t.IsPrime},OutOfStock-{t.OutOfStock}").ToArray();
        var output = string.Join(",", individual);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();

}
```